# how to show only 1 decimal place result

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

```
cast(TotalMinutesAsleep as float64)/60 as sleep_hr
```

The result shows, for example, `5.3666666` but I want `5.3` only.

Comment: Don't you want `5.4` for that example?

Answer (score 0):

According to the source you can use the `ROUND` function.

This should do the trick:

```
round(cast(TotalMinutesAsleep as float64)/60,1) as sleep_hr
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/mathematical_functions#round

Also interesting: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_round.asp